# Sending laravel livewire event from child to parent gives fingerprint error

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Im getting this error when sending an **event** from child to parent container. I am using `wire:key` as recommended but get the JS error `Cannot read property 'fingerprint' of null`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Please see example below.

#### Container

```
class Container extends Component
{
    public $listeners = [
        'submit'
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.container');
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        //dd("The child says wow - it works!");
    }
}
```

with view

```
<div>
    <h1>Im the container</h1>
    @foreach([1,2,3] as $nbr)
        @livewire('child', compact('nbr'))
    @endforeach
</div>
```

#### Child

```
class Child extends Component
{
    public $nbr;

    public function mount($nbr)
    {
        $this->nbr = $nbr;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.child');
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $this->emit('submit', 'wow!');
    }
}
```

with view

```
<div wire:key="{{ $nbr }}">
    Hey im a child
    <button wire:click="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining Livewire components in a loop, you need to give them a key, so Livewire can keep track of each individual component.

```
<div>
    <h1>Im the container</h1>
    @foreach([1,2,3] as $key=>$nbr)
        @livewire('child', compact('nbr'), key($nbr))
    @endforeach
</div>
```

This is done on the component, not on the root-element in the view, meaning that its incorrectly placed with `wire:key="{{ $nbr }}"` being in your child-view.