# Livewire: Unable to update child components after adding new record

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have an issue I can't get my head around. I have set up a structure of components as:

Post -> Comment -> CommentReply

CommentReply emits an event captured by Post. Post updates the comments collection.

The Comment (Model) has self relation as responses.

Now if the comment is top level the view is updated. But if the responses relation is updated the view don't show the update. If I emit a refresh event that is mapped to `$refresh` in `Comment` (component) the component throws error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fingerprint' of null
```

**UPDATE**

`CommentReply.php`

```
public function post_reply () {
     ...
    $new_comment = $this->comment->response()->create($c);
    $this->is_replying = false;
    $this->emit('content:comments:replied', $new_comment);
}
```

`Comment.php` (component)

```
    public $listeners = [
        'content:comments:replied' => 'replied'
    ];

   public function replied($comment) {
        /*
           received as array because type hinting
           created error of array to string conversion
       */
        $c = new CommentModel($comment); 
        $this->comment->responses->prepend($c);
    }
```

`comment.blade.php`

```
<div>
@foreach($comment->responses as $response)
<div>
     <div>
         {{ $response->comment }}
     </div>

     <livewire:comment-reply :comment="$comment" :key="'comment-' . $response->id" />
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

`comment-reply.blade.php`

```
<div x-data="{ replying: @entangle('is_replying') }">
    <button @click="replying = true;" x-show="!replying">Reply</button>
   <div x-show="replying">
       <textarea wire:model.defer="c.comment"></textarea>
       <button wire:click="post_reply">Post</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to key elements in a loop, see this similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64767379/4535200)  I posted a few days ago and also the [official documentation on troubleshooting](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting).

Comment: I have a key attribute already, please see the updated question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I went by this...

1. Created a component `CommentView` and moved the comment display logic to this component
   `comment-view.blade.php`

```
<div>
     <div>
         {{ $comment->comment }}
     </div>

     <livewire:comment-reply :comment="$comment" />
</div>
```

2. `Comment` component has two variables now, the `$comment` and `$responses`, every time the `CommentReply` emits the `content:comments:replied` the `$responses` variable is refreshed.

`Comment.php`

```
    public $listeners = [
        'content:comments:replied' => 'replied'
    ];

   public function replied() {
        $this->responses = $this->comment->responses()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    }
```

`comment.blade.php`

```
<div>
    <livewire:comment-view :comment="$comment" />
    @foreach($responses as $r_comment) 
          <livewire:comment-view :comment="$r_comment" :key="'response-' . $r_comment->id" />
     @endforeach
</div>
```